# xml2 read_html removes closing tags from JSON-LD when using options

Tags: r, rvest, json-ld, xml2

`xml2::read_html(x)` returns the HTML within a linked data JSON object as expected:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

test_ld <- '<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"ReproducibleExample", "description":"<p><strong>text within tags</strong>text after closing tag</p>"'

# tags preserved
test_ld %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()

[1] "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"ReproducibleExample\", \"description\":\"<p><strong>text within tags</strong>text after closing tag</p>\"</script>"
```

Where description contains the HTML `<p><strong>text within tags</strong>text after closing tag</p>`

But if using `xml2::read_html(x, options = 'HUGE')` or with any option (I've tested 5 or 6), the closing tags are removed from the HTML text in a JSON-LD object.

```
# tags removed
test_ld %>% 
  read_html(options = 'HUGE') %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()

# removed
test_ld %>% 
  read_html(options = "NOBLANKS") %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()

# removed
test_ld %>% 
  read_html(options = '') %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()

# all return:
[1] "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"ReproducibleExample\", \"description\":\"<p><strong>text within tagstext after closing tag\"</script>"
```

description now becomes `<p><strong>text within tagstext after closing tag`

Setting options is necessary for some of the HTML I'm parsing. Is it possible to use options and preserve properly formatted HTML from a linked data object?

Answer (score 1):

If multiple options are set the HTML is correct:

```
test_ld %>% 
  read_html(options = c("RECOVER", "NOERROR", "NOBLANKS")) %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()

# or
test_ld %>% 
  read_html(options = c("HUGE", "RECOVER")) %>% 
  html_node('script[type="application/ld+json"]') %>% 
  as.character()


[1] "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"ReproducibleExample\", \"description\":\"<p><strong>text within tags</strong>text after closing tag</p>\"</script>"
```

description is as it should be `<p><strong>text within tags</strong>text after closing tag</p>`